# Skelethonization and Thinning in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have a problem and I can't figure it out.
I have to use two different image processing techniques: [Skelethonization](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm)  and [Thinning](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm) , and I have to do this in java. Now the problem is that I can't find out any starting point or tutorial on this. Can anybody tell me where should I start, or can somebody explain me how can I achieve that? I'm writing the application in Java, and I want to use a `BufferedImage`, if it is possible (of course).

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just take some C implementation of these algorithms and port it to Java?

Comment: Can you point me to some of these algorithms?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to work with images in java, or a tutorial on how to build an algorithm performing these techniques?

Comment: I need a way to implement these 2 techniques in java, or some explications of how pixels should be modified to obtain that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw to the BufferedImage like this:

```
public BufferedImage createSkelethonizationImage() {
   BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height);
   Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();

   // Perform your drawing here
   g2.drawLine(...);

   g2.dispose();
   return image;
}
```

To draw the image, create a new class that extends JComponent and overrides the paint method. Here is some code to get started:

```
public class MyImage extends JComponent {
   // Note: the image should be modified on the Event Dispatch Thread
   private BufferedImage image = createSkelethonizationImage();

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
   }
}
```

Edit - Complete solution:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Width and height of your image
       final int width = 200;
       final int height = 200;

       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
             JFrame frame = new JFrame();
             MyImage image = new MyImage(width, height);
             frame.add(image);
             frame.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
             frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             frame.setVisible(true);            
          }
       });
    }
}

class MyImage extends JComponent {

    // Note: image should be modified on the Event Dispatch Thread only
    private final BufferedImage image;

    public MyImage(int width, int height) {
       image = createSkelethonizationImage(width, height);
       setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    public BufferedImage createSkelethonizationImage(int width, int height) {
       BufferedImage iamge = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
       Graphics2D g2 = iamge.createGraphics();

       // Perform your drawing here
       g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       g2.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);

       g2.dispose();
       return iamge;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
       g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I create the Skelethonization effect? I'm looking for something to start with, to obtain that effect...

Comment: You will need to either find and use a library or implement the algorithm yourself. You might be able to use the source code from the [AnalyzeSkeleton](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=plugin:analysis:analyzeskeleton:start) project. (Note: the Jar download link is broken, but the source code exists on their git site.)

Comment: Ok I will try it and I will come back with an answer :) Thanks